# Fill a field on a web page in TWebBroswer Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, browser, twebbrowser

I'm making a small program to place orders on our supplier's web site. I need to fill 3 fields in the page. Don't even need to "submit" it.

Is there any simple way or any component that could do that (preferably free)

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have an input field with name 'name' and type 'text', you can call

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.GetElementByID('name').setAttribute('value', 'somename');
```

Comment: Alright, but how do you knoe the name of that field? in the source?

Comment: Yes, you would have to look at the webpage's HTML and then code your logic accordingly.

Comment: You'll most probably find your input fields in a 'form' tag.

Comment: Ok I see but wouldn't that code get the value of that field? what i'm trying to do is to write to that field.

Comment: @Gab - I don't understand. To get the value use 'getAttribute', to set it use 'setAttribute'.

Comment: Ok I see now, I'll try that out. Thanks

Comment: @Gab: Good on you for accepting the answer. Just in case you aren't already aware of it: you can both upvote _and_ accept an answer...