# Set focus to an input field in webbrowser

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, twebbrowser

I load an webpage into web-browser component and on that page there is an input field (text). How can I set input focus to that field after the page is loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this similar question [Fill a field on a web page in TWebBroswer Delphi 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568608/fill-a-field-on-a-web-page-in-twebbroswer-delphi-7?lq=1)

You need to first retrieve the text field by calling `getElementById` on the TWebBrowser component's Document property. Once you have the text field you can make the call to `focus`.

```
browserObj.Document.getElementById('MyField').focus
```